# Deploying Sharepoint 2010 solutions to sharepoint 2013 giving me error

Tags: 2013, custom, iis

does anyone have any suggestions where to look for guides when deploying sp 2010 solutions to 2013, 
I've tried everything and keep gettin the error :
Error occurred in deployment step 'Recycle IIS Application Pool': Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
ive tried everything from restarting iis, vs, and the wmi. ive hit a road block, and am wondering if anybody can help me.